# How to check if a cell has a picture?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

In Excel, I want to check if a specific cell for instance "C12" has a picture?
How could I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You do this by looping through Shapes collection of the worksheet, looking for a shape whose `.TopLeftCell` has same address as your target range.

Comment: Is it possible to check whether that shape is picture or icon? because there are various types of shapes

Comment: Also is there a more direct way of doing this, using a Cell and checking it for a picture.

Comment: `.Type` property gives you the type. Please press F2 in the IDE and examine the object model. I never new answer to this question but it took me 10 seconds to look it up in the Object Browser.

Answer (score 2):

I had a situation where I wanted to delete pictures (In my case charts) from selected cells on a worksheet and leave others in place therefore removing all pictures was not an option. I've left behind some debugging and also some extra code to tell the user what is going on.

```
Public Sub RemoveUnWantedGraphs()

    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim rangeToTest As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim shpList

    'Set the rangeToTest variable to the selected cells
    Set rangeToTest = Selection

    'Loop Over the the selected cells
    For Each c In rangeToTest


        'Inner loop to iterate over the shapes collection for the activesheet
        Set shpList = ActiveSheet.Shapes
        For Each shp In shpList

            Application.StatusBar = "Analysing:- " + c.Address + " Graphs To Find:- " & shpList.Count


            'If the address of the current cell and the address
            'of the shape are the same then delete the shape
            If c.Address = shp.TopLeftCell.Address Then

                Debug.Print "Deleting :- " & shp.Name
                shp.Delete

                DoEvents
            End If

        Next shp

    Next c

    Application.StatusBar = ""

    MsgBox "All Shapes In Range Deleted"

End Sub
```

Comment: this cannot work correctly (exept when there is max 1 picture in the range) , when you delete you must start from the end and go to the first `for i=ActiveSheet.Shapes.count to 1 step -1`.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to create a function that will return 1 if image exists in cell, 0 if it does not.  This only works for individual cells and needs modified for multi-cell ranges.

```
Function CellImageCheck(CellToCheck As Range) As Integer
' Return 1 if image exists in cell, 0 if not

    Dim wShape As Shape

    For Each wShape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If wShape.TopLeftCell = CellToCheck Then
            CellImageCheck = 1
        Else
            CellImageCheck = 0
        End If
    Next wShape

End Function
```

This code can then be run using:

```
Sub testFunction()

    If CellImageCheck(Range("B6")) Then
        MsgBox "Image exists!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Image does not exist"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: the function needs to be boolean, and a exit function after you found a Picture would be apreciated, for speed, and for correct answering (if the next pic in the shapes collection is a no go, the function would answer 0)

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each wShape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
If (wShape.Type <> 13) Then wShape.Delete ' If the shape doesn't represent a Picture,     ' delete
Next wShape
```

Comment: when deleting you need to start backward from activesheet.shapes.count or you'll miss some. Also for that goal a simple `ascivesheet.pictures.delete` would do the trick in one line

Answer (score 1):

This is quite an old thread so don't know whether my post will help anybody, but I encountered a similar problem today and after some thinking, derived solution.

I have first stored all range addresses where object exists, to an array and then in the second part of the code, checked each cell address in my selected range for the object against each element in array and carried out execution of tagging to an offset cell if array element address matches active cell address in selected range. Hope, it helps. Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub tagging()
Dim rng As Range, shp As Shape, n As Integer, arr() As String, m As Integer, arrm As Variant
m = 1
n = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count
ReDim arr(n)
For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    arr(m) = shp.TopLeftCell.Address
    m = m + 1
Next
   For Each rng In Selection
       m = 1
       For Each arrm In arr
           If rng.Address = arr(m) Then
              rng.Offset(0, 30).Value = "Yes"
              Exit For
           Else
              rng.Offset(0, 30).Value = "No"
           End If
                If m < n Then
                   m = m + 1
                Else
                   Exit For
                End If
      Next
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Juhi's approach helped me.  I think there's an implied need in the original question to apply this to multiple cells or a contiguous range or even a whole sheet.  In such a case, it's desirable not to consider each cell separately and loop through every shape in the sheet repeatedly for all the cells of interest.

I've changed the functionality a little to remove the nested loop and enter text into all the cells that contain a shape.  This is optimised for my immediate need where the source data is a 4x40 cell region where the cells either contain a Shape or nothing at all. My method doesn't enter 'no' for the cells that contain no shape, but it's easy to enter that into the blank cells at the end.

```
Sub MarkCellsWithShapes()

    Dim rng As Range, shp As Shape, n As Integer, arr() As String, m As Integer, arrm As Variant

    n = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count
    ReDim arr(n)
    
    m = 1

    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        arr(m) = shp.TopLeftCell.Address
        Range(arr(m)) = "Yes"
        m = m + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

If you need to work in a specific range rather than a whole sheet, you could make the 'yes' instruction conditional (see [VBA test if cell is in a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183374/vba-test-if-cell-is-in-a-range) for tips on that).