# VBA test if cell is in a range

Tags: excel, vba

I want to test if a given cell is within a given range in Excel VBA. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: any feedback about the proposed answers? Isn't cool asking without checking the proposed answers, as the answers took their time looking for your solution.

Answer (score 36):

From the Help:

```
Set isect = Application.Intersect(Range("rg1"), Range("rg2"))
If isect Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Ranges do not intersect"
Else
    isect.Select
End If
```

Comment: This is not protected against errors in `Application.Intersect`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27838714/2707864)

Answer (score 14):

[Determine if a cell is within a range using VBA in Microsoft Excel](http://www.exceltip.com/st/Determine_if_a_cell_is_within_a_range_using_VBA_in_Microsoft_Excel/484.html):

From the linked site (maintaining credit to original submitter):

> VBA macro tip contributed by [Erlandsen Data Consulting](http://www.erlandsendata.no/english/)
>   offering Microsoft Excel Application development, template customization,
>   support and training solutions

```
Function InRange(Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range) As Boolean
    ' returns True if Range1 is within Range2
    InRange = Not (Application.Intersect(Range1, Range2) Is Nothing)
End Function


Sub TestInRange()
    If InRange(ActiveCell, Range("A1:D100")) Then
        ' code to handle that the active cell is within the right range
        MsgBox "Active Cell In Range!"
    Else
        ' code to handle that the active cell is not within the right range
        MsgBox "Active Cell NOT In Range!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @mwolfe02 a while ago I posted an external link and has been suggested to paste the code rather than the link itself (to avoid problems with external sites going offline or something like this).
So, I'd suggest you to paste the code _plus_ the link.

Comment: @Tiago:  I was hesitant to do that due to potential copyright issues.  I've added the original attribution to give the author his fair due.  Hopefully, this walks the fine line between plagiarism and helpfulness.

Comment: @mwolfe02 agree, buddy. I'm just following other user's suggestions, as I'm a newbie around here.

Comment: Why encapsulate the original function into another one that just reduces its functionnality without any added value ? That's a perfect  example "useless fat programming".

Comment: True enough.  I should have read the code more closely.  That was just the first link that popped up in google for "excel vba cell in range".  I should have edited to just include the pertinent excel function.  I cede that your answer is the better one.

Comment: The added value is improved clarity and reduced clutter in the client code.  The cost is additional library code.  Auxiliary library code gets increasingly beneficial as it's used more and as the overall complexity of the client code rises.

Also, I'd trim InRange down to "InRange = Not Application.Intersect(Range1, Range2) is Nothing".  The additional variable adds more complexity than it saves.

Comment: GatesDA is correct: InRange = Not (Application.Intersect(Range1, Range2)) Is Nothing does not yield correct values in some vba-versions.

Answer (score 14):

If the two ranges to be tested (your *given cell* and your *given range*) are not in the same `Worksheet`, then **`Application.Intersect` throws an error**. Thus, a way to **avoid it** is with something like

```
Sub test_inters(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range)
    If (rng1.Parent.Name = rng2.Parent.Name) Then
        Dim ints As Range
        Set ints = Application.Intersect(rng1, rng2)
        If (Not (ints Is Nothing)) Then
            ' Do your job
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't work with contiguous ranges all the time. My solution for non-contiguous ranges is as follows (includes some code from other answers here):

```
Sub test_inters()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim inters As Range

    Set rng2 = Worksheets("Gen2").Range("K7")
    Set rng1 = ExcludeCell(Worksheets("Gen2").Range("K6:K8"), rng2)

    If (rng2.Parent.name = rng1.Parent.name) Then
        Dim ints As Range
        MsgBox rng1.Address & vbCrLf _
        & rng2.Address & vbCrLf _

        For Each cell In rng1
            MsgBox cell.Address
            Set ints = Application.Intersect(cell, rng2)
            If (Not (ints Is Nothing)) Then
                MsgBox "Yes intersection"
            Else
                MsgBox "No intersection"
            End If
        Next cell
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

@mywolfe02 gives a static range code so his inRange works fine but if you want to add dynamic range then use this one with inRange function of him.this works better with when you want to populate data to fix starting cell and last column is also fixed.

```
Sub DynamicRange()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim StartCell As Range
Dim rng As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("xyz")
LastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row
Set rng = Workbooks("Record.xlsm").Worksheets("xyz").Range(Cells(12, 2), Cells(LastRow, 12))

Debug.Print LastRow

If InRange(ActiveCell, rng) Then
'        MsgBox "Active Cell In Range!"
  Else
      MsgBox "Please select the cell within the range!"
  End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option to see if a cell exists inside a range. In case you have issues with the Intersect solution as I did.

```
If InStr(range("NamedRange").Address, range("IndividualCell").Address) > 0 Then
    'The individual cell exists in the named range
Else
    'The individual cell does not exist in the named range
End If
```

InStr is a VBA function that checks if a string exists within another string.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/instr-function

Comment: Very far from best!
Try it when checking if `B2` is within `A1:C3`.