# VBA:How to check cell range?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell name called `Book.a`,I have to check in `if` condition if the cell is in a range(`B1:I10`).How to do this?
I tried 'intersect' method for this but didn`t work for me.
Please suggest some answers.

Comment: I am taking my comment back. :) Check out both answers with `intersect method`

Comment: Damn! I posted without searching SO!!! possible duplicate of [VBA test if cell is in a range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183374/vba-test-if-cell-is-in-a-range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim rng As Range

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = Application.Intersect(.Range("Book.a"), .Range("B1:I10"))
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Range `Book.a` is a part of `B1:I10`"
        Else
            MsgBox "Range `Book.a` not found or is not a part of `B1:I10`"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be possible to search for named range within a range. So I take my comment back. 
What you can try is this: For each named range that is like `book.a`, **you can check if its address [`intersect`](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/vba-intersect.htm) the given main range**..

```
Dim objName As Name
Dim mainRange as Range

Sheet1.Unprotect
Set mainRange = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B1:I10")
For Each objName In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    strName = objName.Name
    If InStr(1, strName, "book.a", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
      If Intersect(objName.Address, mainRange) Is Nothing then
        '-- not within
      Else
        '-- within
      End If
    End If
Next
Sheet1.Protect
```