# Determine if range has data

Tags: excel, vba

The following code creates a chart from a named Range "Table24".

There will be times when this table has no valid data and then I want the range of my dataset to be a cell with 0 and populate the chart with no data.

This is for the 4th out of 5 charts- using debug I determined that this is the code which crashes my Excel file every time it's run:

```vb
'//////////////////CHART 4 Creation //////////////////////////////
Set myChtRange = ws.Range("L43:R63")
' What range contains data for chart
 
If ws.Range("Table24").Rows.Count > 0 Then
    Set myDataRange = ws.ListObjects("Table24").ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange
Else
    Set myDataRange = ws.Range("K1")
End If

' Cover chart range with chart
Set objChart = .ChartObjects.Add( _
    Left:=myChtRange.Left, Top:=myChtRange.Top, _
    Width:=myChtRange.Width, Height:=myChtRange.Height)
' Put all the right stuff in the chart
With objChart.Chart
    .ChartArea.AutoScaleFont = False
    .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    .ChartStyle = 214
    .SetSourceData Source:=myDataRange
    .Parent.Name = "Chart4"
    .HasTitle = True
    .HasLegend = False
    .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Most Tolerance Holds"
    .ChartTitle.Font.Bold = True
    .ChartTitle.Font.Size = 15
  
    If ws.Range("Table24").Rows.Count > 0 Then
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = ws.ListObjects("Table24").ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange
    Else
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = ws.Range("K1")
    End If

    With .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
        .HasTitle = True
        With .AxisTitle
            .Characters.Text = " "
            .Font.Size = 10
            .Font.Bold = True
        End With
    End With
    With .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
        .HasTitle = True
        .DisplayUnit = none
        .HasDisplayUnitLabel = False
        .TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0.0"
        With .AxisTitle
            .Characters.Text = "Lines"
            .Font.Size = 15
            .Font.Bold = True
        End With
    End With
End With
```

I tried:

```vb
If ws.ListObjects("Table24").DataBodyRange.Rows.Count > 0 Then

If NOT ws.ListObjects("Table24").DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
```

And even the IS Empty

I need help creating the argument when the table looks like this:
[image]

The named range "Table24" does exist. The table has no data in it.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer: 
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("Table24")) = 1 Then

Answer (score 8):

The databodyrange property of a listobject represents the range of data. if there is no data in the list object, then the range has nothing

```
if ws.ListObjects("Table24").DataBodyRange is Nothing then
  'Do something if there is no data
Else
  'Do something if there is data
end if
```

Comment: If any blank rows were added to the table then the DataBodyRange property will contain a range (it is -not- Nothing) and this logic might not behave as expected.  If the purpose is to avoid throwing an error by referencing DataBodyRange then this is fine.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is old but for anyone reading this, the correct way to check for an empty table is using *ListRows.Count.*

This will give zero if the table is empty. In other words, if you delete all the rows in a table then *ListRows.Count* will be zero.

```
If Sheet1.ListObjects("Table").ListRows.Count = 0 Then
    ' empty
Else
    ' not empty
End If
```

Comment: Thx but why do you think this is better than those in the other answers?

Comment: @Alper Because it looks simpler and it is immediately clear to the reader what it does. To me all other answers are rubbish... To maintain this code is really much easier than to mantain code from any other answer...

Answer (score 2):

Add this function (taken [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183374/vba-test-if-cell-is-in-a-range/27838714#27838714)):

```
Function DBRRangeTest(rng1 As Range, Optional rng2 As Range)
    ' DataBodyRange Range Test

    ' Test if rng1 and rng2 intersect
    If rng2 Is Nothing Then
        ' Either no argument was supplied or the supplied argument was empty
        DBRRangeTest = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    If (rng1.Parent.Name = rng2.Parent.Name) Then
        Dim ints As Range
        Set ints = Application.Intersect(rng1, rng2)
        If (Not (ints Is Nothing)) Then
            DBRRangeTest = True
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Then, replace this:

```
If ws.Range("Table24").Rows.Count > 0 Then

Set myDataRange = ws.ListObjects("Table24").ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange

Else

Set myDataRange = ws.Range("K1")

End If
```

with this:

```
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ws.ListObject("Table24")

If DBRRangeTest(tbl.HeaderRowRange.Offset(1), tbl.DataBodyRange) Then
    ' If this test returns true, it means that there is a valid databodyrange _
    ' but we have no guarantee whether the cell is empty or not, because DataBodyRange _
    ' will return with an address if there *has* been a value in its range.
    ' So we'll test manually.
    If tbl.HeaderRowRange.Offset(1).Value <> "" Then
        Set myDataRange = tbl.ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange
    Else
        Set myDataRange = ws.Range("K1")
    End If
Else
    ' The test returned false, which essentially is the same as _
    ' DataBodyRange Is Nothing.
    Set myDataRange = ws.Range("K1")
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll share the function I use.  It returns TRUE if a ListObject (table) is empty below the header row and above total row.  (It still works if the table isn't displaying either the header or total row.)

This function checks for 1 of 4 possibilities:

1. If the ListObject (table) variable "Is Nothing" it generates an easy to understand error.
2. If the table doesn't have a DataBodyRange (no data was added below the header and above the total row and no blank rows were added to the table except for the row automatically created when the table was created) then it returns `False`.
3. If the table has a DataBodyRange but every cell below the header and above the total row is `Empty` (does not contain a value, not even a zero length vbNullString character) then it returns `False`.
4. If **(a)** the table has a DataBodyRange *and* **(b)** at least one cell below the header and above the total row is NOT `Empty` (contains any value, including a zero length vbNullString character) then it returns `False`.

### Function IsEmptyTable()

```
Public Function IsEmptyTable(ByVal target As Excel.ListObject) As Boolean        

    Const APPNAME As String = "IsEmptyTable()"

    If target Is Nothing Then
        ' The parameter doesn't contain a ListObject (table).
        Err.Raise 2310, _
                  APPNAME, _
                  APPNAME & String$(2, vbNewLine) & "Parameter 'target' must refer to a valid ListObject (table)."

    ElseIf target.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
        ' The table doesn't have a databody range and therefore has no data below
        '   the header row and above the total row.
        IsEmptyTable = True

    Else
        ' The table has a DataBodyRange.
        '   Check it for any non-empty cells (including zero-length
        '   vbNullString).  Return TRUE if any are found.
        IsEmptyTable = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountA(target.DataBodyRange) = 0

    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but thought to put an answer here:

An Empty table could either mean:

- it does not have an ListRows added - i.e. DataBodyRange will be Nothing.
- its 1st ListRow cells are empty - i.e. DataBodyRange will NOT be Nothing, but DataBodyRange Count will be 0.

for e.g.

' To check if ListObject does not have any ListRows added:

```
If Sheet1.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange Is Nothing then 
    Sheet1.ListObjects(1).ListRows.Add
End If
```

' If ListObject has atleast 1 ListRow but need to check if ListObject DataBodyRange is Empty, then:

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet1.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange) = 0 Then
    ' do something
End If
```