# Only copy if the table has data

Tags: excel, vba

I have three different tables that sends data too another tables in a different sheets when I push a button. However when one or two of the tables are empty I want excel to ignore the empty table/s

I've tried using this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29639474/vba-counting-rows-in-a-table-list-object) but it only adds a new blank row

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("Storningar")) = 1 Then
    tblStorning.DataBodyRange.Copy
    TargetTblLastRow.Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
 End If
```

Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36027393/vba-excel-determine-if-table-has-data) one also but same result:

```
If tblStorning.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
   'Do something if there is no data
Else
  tblStorning.DataBodyRange.Copy
  TargetTblLastRow.Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'Do something if there is data
End If
```

This is what the sub looks for one of the tables that sends data from table to the other one without the IF statements

```
Sub SkickaStorningar()

Dim tblStorning As ListObject
Dim tblStorningOuput As ListObject
Dim TargetTblLastRow As Variant

Set tblStorning = Worksheets("Rapport").ListObjects("Storningar")
Set tblStorningOutput = Worksheets("Storningar").ListObjects("StorningsTabell")
Set TargetTblLastRow = tblStorningOutput.ListRows.Add

tblStorning.DataBodyRange.Copy
TargetTblLastRow.Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


End Sub
```

When I push the button to send the tables I just want to send the tables that has data and ignore the ones that dont

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you tried `ListObject.ListRows.Count` to check for 0s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit with new info:
You probably have something like this:

```
Sub SkickaStorningar()

Dim tblStorning As ListObject
Dim tblStorningOuput As ListObject
Dim TargetTblLastRow As Variant

Set tblStorning = Worksheets("Rapport").ListObjects("Storningar")
Set tblStorningOutput = Worksheets("Storningar").ListObjects("StorningsTabell")
Set TargetTblLastRow = tblStorningOutput.ListRows.Add ' Always adds a row

If tblStorning.ListRows.Count > 0 Then
    tblStorning.DataBodyRange.Copy
    TargetTblLastRow.Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If

End Sub
```

Every time you run this macro, you're adding a new blank row in your target table. You should only add a row if the if statement evaluates `TRUE`. Like this:

```
Sub SkickaStorningar()

Dim tblStorning As ListObject
Dim tblStorningOuput As ListObject
Dim TargetTblLastRow As Variant

Set tblStorning = Worksheets("Rapport").ListObjects("Storningar")
Set tblStorningOutput = Worksheets("Storningar").ListObjects("StorningsTabell")

If tblStorning.ListRows.Count > 0 Then
    Set TargetTblLastRow = tblStorningOutput.ListRows.Add ' Only execute ListRows.Add if you want to add a row
    tblStorning.DataBodyRange.Copy
    TargetTblLastRow.Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this how it should look? Because it still adds an empty row at the bottom of "StorningsTabell"
```
If tblStorning.ListRows.Count > 0 Then
    tblStorning.DataBodyRange.Copy
    TargetTblLastRow.Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues ' If the above is true, there's data in your databody range
Else
' There is no data
End If
```

Comment: `ListRows.Add` will always add a blank row. Are you sure the paste logic is working? Are you sure that there's really no data in the table? If any of the cells have formulas or characters, even if they're not displaying in the cell, `ListRows.Count` will return >0.

Comment: When I run
`Sub testing()

 MsgBox ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Storningar").ListRows.Count

End Sub`
It returns a 0

Comment: Every time you run your routine, `Set TargetTblLastRow = tblStorningOutput.ListRows.Add` adds a blank row before you check whether there's data in your source table. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim table As ListObject

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<- Change sheet name if needed

        Set table = .ListObjects("tblTest") '<- Change table name

        If Not table.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
            'Code
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```