# DataBodyRange Rows - Variable object or with-block not defined error

Tags: excel, vba

I run this code in VBA and can't find why I get the 91 error. I really checked on Google before posting, thanks by advance for your answers.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Suppression_lignes_tableau()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set ws = Sheets("Tirage_1")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Tableau2")
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, n As Integer, m As Integer, tempString As Integer, tempInteger As Integer
n = Sheets("Tirage_1").Range("C10")
m = Sheets("Tirage_1").Range("C11")
'Delete toutes les lignes du tableau
    
    With tbl.DataBodyRange
      If .Rows.Count > 1 Then
        .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Rows.Delete
      End If
    End With
tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows(1).ClearContents
'Ajoute toutes les lignes incrémentées dans la table
For i = 1 To n
Sheets("Tirage_1").Range("a" & i + 11) = i
Next i
For i = 1 To n
    Cells(i + 11, 2).Value = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 100 * n)
Next i
For i = 1 To n
    For j = i + 1 To n
    If Cells(j + 11, 2).Value(i + 11, 2).Value Then
    tempString = Cells(i + 11, 1).Value
    Cells(i + 11, 1).Value = Cells(j + 11, 1).Value
    Cells(j + 11, 1).Value = tempString
    tempInteger = Cells(i + 11, 2).Value
    Cells(i + 11, 2).Value = Cells(j + 11, 2).Value
    Cells(j + 11, 2).Value = tempInteger
    End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

The error happens on the line :
`If .Rows.Count > 1 Then`

Julien

Comment: Most likely your table is empty so `DataBodyRange` is `Nothing`. You can test for `tbl.ListRows.Count` instead.

Comment: Similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36027393/determine-if-range-has-data

Comment: Thanks Raymond !! It worked greatly. I probably need some training with this language.

Answer (score 0):

check whether tbl.DataRange is not Nothing before:

```
If Not tbl.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
    With tbl.DataBodyRange
      If .Rows.Count > 1 Then
        .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Rows.Delete
      End If
    End With
End If
```