# How can I test if a selection is completely within a range?

Tags: vba, excel, intersection, named-ranges

So i have found this which is similar:
[VBA test if cell is in a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183374/vba-test-if-cell-is-in-a-range)

but this seems to be testing (as I understand it) if the cells selected intersect the range at all.  However I need to find a way to confirm if the selected range is COMPLETELY within the range so that I can restrict the macro to only work inside a specified range of cells.

here is what I've got so far....I name the selected cells as a range (sel_rng) and set them as a variable....then I name the acceptable range as a named range (okay_rng)....then (hopefully....but this is the part I'm still unclear how to pull off) if "sel_rng" lies completely within "okay_rng" I want to grab "sel_rng" and merge it, otherwise throw up an error"

```
Sub Merge_Cells()
'
' Merge_Cells Macro
Dim selcells As Range
Selection.Name = "sel_rng"
selcells = Range("sel_rng")

Dim okayrng As Integer
okayrng = Range("itemrows").Value + 28
ActiveSheet.Range("C29:C" & okayrng).Select
Selection.Name = "okay_rng"



Range("sel_rng").Select
Selection.Merge
```

Thoughts anyone?

Comment: why are you not trying what your link is suggesting?

Comment: Also, you can't merge the `selcells` if they are already part of the `okayrng` range.

Comment: As I understood it, the solution of "intersect" just tells if part of my selcells range is or is not within okayrng....I need to confirm that ALL of it is within the range.  Am i misinterpreting this?

Answer (score 0):

The intersection of the two ranges will determine if one range is completely within another range.

```
dim rng1 as range, rng2 as range

set rng1 = range("b2:c3")
set rng2 = range("a1:d4")    

'if rng1 is completely within rng2, the intersection's address will be the same as rng1's address
if application.intersect(rng1, rng2).address = rng1.address then
    debug.print rng1.address(0, 0) & " is within " & rng2.address(0, 0)
end if
```

btw, there is the possibility that the intersect could be nothing. You should add error handling for that.