# How to change a cell value based on active/selected cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a list of names in a **Range A2:A77**, in the worksheet name called **Manual**. whenever i choose a name, that is when a cell gets selected from the range, that active cell value should get reflected in the cell **C1**. Also, the macro should not work incase if i selected else where, other than the given worksheet or range.

I have googled alot but nothing seem to be matching my criteria, so i'm here, hoping for a better solution. You may ask me to achieve this by using data validation, but for that i will have to do multiple clicks and scrolling work to be done everytime. so to avoid that i'm looking for vba code to minimize the work and time.
Thank You.

Comment: Best to include your attempt at least. This kind of stuff gets asked on a regular basis and there should be plenty of posts explaining the mechanics of a selectionchange event, test if selection is just a single cell, test if it intersects a certain range etc.. And yes datavalidation seems more appropriate imo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am only just learning VBA at the moment so this could be some very horible code but here goes.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cells As Range
    Set cells = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A27")
    If Not (Intersect(Target, cells) Is Nothing) Then
       ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Value = Target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

`Worksheet_SelectionChange` is called if the selected cell in the sheet changes then using the test from `InRange` that I found here: [VBA test if cell is in a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183374/vba-test-if-cell-is-in-a-range) test if the cell is within the defined range then set the values.

Edited as sugested by @Vitaliy Prushak in comments.

Comment: Note: If a range of cells is selected then the first value (and only the first value) that falls within the `cells` range is coppied into C1.

Comment: you can simply replace `If InRange(Target, cells) Then` with `If Not (Intersect(Target, cells) Is Nothing) Then` and get rid of additional function.

Comment: @lain McL though you are a beginner, your code works brilliantly.