# OpenXml: Determining the Image in a Cell in Excel

Tags: c#, openxml, excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if a cell has a picture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320826/how-to-check-if-a-cell-has-a-picture)
>   [OpenXML: Excel, extracting Cell text and Image/Picture data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993979/openxml-excel-extracting-cell-text-and-image-picture-data)

I have An Excel document with 4 images, each in a cell A1,A2,A3,A4

I can iterate thru all the images in the worksheet, but I need to be able to edit this function to give me the image in "A1" and "A2" for instance

```
    [Test]
    public void IterateThruImages()
    {
        WorkbookPart wbPart = document.WorkbookPart;
        var workSheet = wbPart.WorksheetParts.FirstOrDefault();

        foreach(ImagePart i in workSheet.DrawingsPart.GetPartsOfType<ImagePart>())
        {
            Stream stream = i.GetStream();
            long length = stream.Length;
            byte[] byteStream = new byte[length];
            stream.Read(byteStream, 0, (int)length);

            var imageAsString = Convert.ToBase64String(byteStream);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oops, wrong close vore here. Sorry.

Comment: Images in Excel are never "in" cells, but just "over" them.  Checking the location of the image will give you the underlying cell.  In VBA images/shapes have a `TopLeftCell` property: I'm not familiar with OpenXml so I don't know if that's exposed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to get the relationship id "rId" of the image. You get that by getting the TwoCellAnchor of the row/col in question. Then get the Embed. Use that to get the image.

```
    [Test]
    public void GetImageRelationshipIdAndImageOfThatId()
    {
        string row = "1";
        string col = "0";

        WorkbookPart wbPart = document.WorkbookPart;
        var workSheet = wbPart.WorksheetParts.FirstOrDefault();

        TwoCellAnchor cellHoldingPicture = workSheet.DrawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing.OfType<TwoCellAnchor>()
             .Where(c => c.FromMarker.RowId.Text == row && 
                    c.FromMarker.ColumnId.Text == col).FirstOrDefault();

        var picture = cellHoldingPicture.OfType<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.Picture>().FirstOrDefault();
        string rIdofPicture = picture.BlipFill.Blip.Embed;

        Console.WriteLine("The rID of this Anchor's [{0},{1}] Picture is '{2}'" ,row,col, rIdofPicture);

        ImagePart imageInThisCell = (ImagePart)workSheet.DrawingsPart.GetPartById(rIdofPicture);

    }
```