# How to check if a cell in an excel document (.xlsx and .xls) contains images using ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, office-interop

I have written the below code to check if an excel worksheet has images, its not working. I have inserted an image in cell A1 of the excel sheet.

```
Application MSExcelApp= new Application();
Workbook MSExcelWB = MSExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(file);
Worksheet MSExcelWS = MSExcelWB.Sheets[1];
MSExcelWB.CheckCompatibility = false;
MSExcelWB.DoNotPromptForConvert = true;
MSExcelWB.UpdateRemoteReferences = false;
MSExcelWB.EnableAutoRecover = false;
MSExcelWB.SaveLinkValues = false;
MSExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
MSExcelApp.AutoRecover.Enabled = false;
Range MSExcelRange = MSExcelWS.UsedRange;
int rowCount = MSExcelRange.Rows.Count;
int colCount = MSExcelRange.Columns.Count;
if (colCount > 0 && rowCount > 0)
{                   
    for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 1; k <= rowCount; k++)
        {
            Range CellRange = MSExcelRange.Cells[j, k] as Range;
            foreach (Shape wShape in MSExcelWS.Shapes)
            {
                if (wShape.TopLeftCell == CellRange)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("True");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
MSExcelWB.Close();
MSExcelApp.Quit();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(MSExcelRange);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(MSExcelWS);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(MSExcelWB);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(MSExcelApp);
```

Comment: hi Try this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994216/openxml-determining-the-image-in-a-cell-in-excel) hope it will help u