# how to check if the value stored in a excel cell is an image

Tags: c#, excel, image

I have an Excel file and there are images placed on some cells.
I want to have c# code to check if the value in a specific cell is number or is an image.
i tried the following code:

```
var cellValue =  (xlWorkSheet.Cells[10, 2] as Excel.Range).Value;
if (cellValue == null)// probably it is a image
{
    // do things
}
```

this works most of the time but if the cell is empty then I can not detect if the there is image in the cell or the cell is empty as both cases return null.

is there any better way to do this ?
many thanks

Comment: You do this by looping through Shapes collection of the worksheet, looking for a shape whose .TopLeftCell has same address as your target range. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320826/how-to-check-if-a-cell-has-a-picture

Comment: An image is not stored in a cell. It is stored in Shapes collection.